# runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { punctuation (token) issue

Tags: android, runnable, timertask, punctuation, android-runonuithread

Somehow it doesn't work, according to me it should be this:

```
public void Splash(){
    Timer timer= new Timer();

    timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){ 

    MexGame.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      public void run(){
      SplashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);
      } //Closes run()

      }); //Closes runOnUiThread((){})

  },SplashTime); //Closes the Timeratask((){})

} //closes Splash()
```

Anybody any idea where I'm missing something?

*FORMAL COMMENT*
I know silly issue, or maybe I'm doing something impossible, but I tried all the logical possibilities. So probably missing something or I'm trying to do something that is not possible.
Can you please help me out.
I'm trying to use the following code, but that gives token issues:

```
 Timer timer= new Timer();
   timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

     runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      public void run(){
      SplashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);}

      });}

  },SplashTime);
```

If I block out the runOnUiThread it crashes since I'm trying to adapt the UI from another thread, but at least no token issue, anybody any idea?:

```
   Timer timer= new Timer();


  timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){

//   runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

      public void run(){
      SplashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);}

    //  });}

  },SplashTime);
```

Comment: have you tried using Activity_name.this.runOnUiThread(...)?

Comment: Hi Lalit, gives the same issue, eclipse gives me the comment that I should add or remove ; and } { etc. Without things blocked out the comment I get is at the line with timer.schedule and SplashTime on the end. It seems Eclipse doesn't recognize the Timer Task when the runOnUiThread is added..

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both the TimerTask and the Runnable require you to implement a run method, so you'll need two `run` methods.

Also your code will be more easy to read if you separate the construction of the Runnable from the construction of the TimerTask.

```
   final Runnable setImageRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
             splashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);
        }
    };

    TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
        public void run() {
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(setImageRunnable);
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(task, splashTime);
```

Comment: +, I missed the lack of `run()` for `TimerTask`

Answer (score 1):

You have excess "}" before `SplashTime`. You've commented one openning "{" and two closing "}", so your original code have one unrequired "}".

```
Timer timer= new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask(){
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run(){
                SplashImage.setImageDrawable(aktieknop);
            }   //closes run(){}         
        });     //closes runOnUiThread( Runnable(){ }); 
    },          //closes TimerTask(){}
    SplashTime);
```